# Extracting Data from a Nested Dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I am new here, this is my first question. We all start somewhere :D

I have this data being returned to me via an API and I store it in a variable named `jsonResponseData`

```
{
    "date-value": [{
        "dateTime": "2020-06-25",
        "value": "34365"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26",
        "value": "7268"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-27",
        "value": "4762"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-28",
        "value": "4650"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-29",
        "value": "2934"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-30",
        "value": "4973"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-07-01",
        "value": "3594"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-07-02",
        "value": "19674"
    }]
}
```

Is this even a nested dictionary? I am fairly new to programming and any help is welcome!
Regardless of what it is, how would I parse it so I only keep the 7 `value` values and am able to then add them up into one number.

Comment: Are you going to get sum of these fields? "value": "4650"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the list, and access the dict inside.

```py
for entry in data['date-value']:
    print(entry['value'])
    # or whatever else you want to do with the values
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm. I will accept this as an answer in 10 minutes once it lets me. One more question: Is a nested dictionary the correct terminology?

Comment: I would have called it a list of dictionaries. (Although they are technically nested inside 'date-value', we access the list directly)

Answer (score 2):

```
values = [x["value"] for x in jsonResponseData["date-value"]]
```

List Comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a nested dictionary. Instead of using a loop, you can use list comprehension.

```
>>> sum(int([inner['value']) for inner in my_dict['date-value']])
82220
```

> For each nested dictionary in my_dict, turn the 'value' element into an integer and sum the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function which will return the sum of the values. Hope this helps!

```
def getValuesSum(json_data):
    values_list=[int(items['value']) for items in json_data['date-value']]
    return sum(values_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to extract those values (given that the object above is called `dict`).

```
for val in dict["date-value"]:
  print(val["value"])
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this even a nested dictionary?

Sort of. It's a dictionary with a list of dictionaries inside it.

> Regardless of what it is, how would I parse it so I only keep the 7 value values and am able to then add them up into one number.

Try this:

```
import json

data = """
{
    "date-value": [{
        "dateTime": "2020-06-25",
        "value": "34365"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26",
        "value": "7268"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-27",
        "value": "4762"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-28",
        "value": "4650"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-29",
        "value": "2934"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-30",
        "value": "4973"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-07-01",
        "value": "3594"
    }, {
        "dateTime": "2020-07-02",
        "value": "19674"
    }]
}
"""

data_dict = json.loads(data)

values = 0
for x in data_dict["date-value"]:
    values += int(x['value'])

print(values)
```

That should result in values being the sum of all 7 numbers.